# TextField in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to put UITextField instead of Navigation Title:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.text = "Title"
    self.navigationItem.titleView = textField
}
```

and when I run the app I see text "Title", but when I try to edit this text field text become invisible.

Comment: Try dragging a UITextField to the navigation bar in storyboard, it's usually more reliable

Comment: Thanks, it really works fine.

Comment: @RonakShah you must post your answer as Answer, please post a picture and you will get some points and will be better for S.O

Comment: @FuzzzzyBoy I posted my answer properly, would it be possible for you to accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try dragging a UITextField to the navigation bar in storyboard, it's usually more reliable.

[image: Dragging it]

[image: Complete!]